# convert a Map<String, List<MyObject> to List<Map<String, MyObject>> in java

Tags: java, data-structures

I want to convert a `Map<String, List<MyObject>> to List<Map<String, MyObject>>`

`{<key1,[myObject1, myObject2]>, <key2,[myObject3, myObject4]>}
will be converted to 
[{<key1,myObject1>, <key2,myObject3>}, {<key1,myObject2>, <key2, myObject4>}]`

where myObject1 and myObject3 have a same unique id and so do myObject2 and myObject4.

my implementation is below but is there a more optimal way of doing this.

```
private List<Map<String, MyObject>> getObjectMapList( Map<String, List<MyObject>> objectMap)

{
  List<Map<String, MyObject>> objectMapList = new ArrayList<Map<String,MyObject>>();

 for(MyObject myObject : objectMap.get("key1")) {// there will be default key1 whose value is known

        Map<String, MyObject> newMap= new HashMap<String, MyObject>();
        for (String key : objectMap.keySet()) {
            newMap.put(key, objectMap.get(key).stream()
                    .filter(thisObject -> thisObject.getId().equals(myObject.getId()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0));
        }
        objectMapList.add(newMap);
    }
    return objectMapList;

}
```

Comment: Where does the `language` variable come from?

Comment: was some typo. edited it

Answer (score 1):

Here's a 1-liner without any curly brackets:

```
private List<Map<String, MyObject>> getObjectMapList( Map<String, List<MyObject>> objectMap) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
      .map(e -> e.getValue().stream()
      .map(o -> Collections.singletonMap(e.getKey(), o))
      .collect(Collections.toList())
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collections.toList());
}
```

The main "trick" here is the use of [`Collections.singletonMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap-K-V-) to allow a blockless in-line create-and-populate of a map.

---

<sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>

Comment: Looks nice, I will keep the `singletonMap` in mind. But does this still group the pairs by `MyObject.getId()`? Or does each map in the result list only contain one mapping?

Comment: @MalteHartwig only one mapping

Answer (score 0):

This stream should return you the desired result. With my old Eclipse version, I had some trouble with types. You might have to break it up into single steps, or add some types in the lambdas, but I wanted to keep it short.

```
Map<String, List<MyObject>> objectMap = new HashMap<>();

objectMap.keySet()
         .stream()
         .flatMap(key -> objectMap.get(key)
                                  .stream()
                                  .map(obj -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, obj)))
         .collect(groupingBy(pair -> pair.getValue().getId()))
         .values()
         .stream()
         .map(listOfSameIds -> listOfSameIds.stream()
                                            .collect(toMap(SimpleEntry::getKey, SimpleEntry::getValue)))
         .collect(toList());
```

What I do is:

1. Pair all the objects in all your input's values with their keys and put them in one long list (`flatMap(key -> streamOfKeyObjectPairs)`).
2. Separate those pairs by the IDs of the objects (`collect(groupingBy)`).
3. Take each of those groups and convert the lists of pairs into maps (`map(list -> toMap)`)
4. Put all those maps into a list

Comment: I was not able to get it work. groupingBy(pair -> pair.getValue().getId()) complains about unknown object event if split is into different operations

Comment: Did you add the import for the groupingBy method? Write `Collectors.groupingBy` to check whether the import is missing. Otherwise, you could try to explicitly type the `pair` parameter by replacing `pair -> pair.getValue().getId()` by `(SimpleEntry<String, MyObject> pair) -> pair.getValue().getId()`. If that still does not work, you could try assigning the lambda to a Function variable: `Function<SimpleEntry<String, MyObject>, ID_TYPE> toID = pair -> pair.getValue().getId()`.